# Appending to file issue

Tags: powershell

I'm running a script that appends computer names to a file, and for some reason it started appending them looking like this:

C O M P U T E R 1

C O M P U T E R 2

C O M P U T E R 3

It didn't used to append them like this. What the script does is it grab all of my workstations, excluding servers, read in the list of successfully changed computers, use that as the filter against the full list of workstations, go through changing the password on the remaining workstations, appending the successes to the list of successfully changed computers, then at the end it would read in the successfully changed list, use it as the filter for the full list of workstations, and write out an updated list of remaining workstations. It also populates a file with all the errors. The only append that is showing up weird is the Successful one. The others append fine.

Here's my script:

```
$time = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30)
$AllComputers = Get-adcomputer -filter "OperatingSystem -notlike '*server*'" -properties * |Where-Object {$_.LastLogonDate -gt $time -and ($_.Enabled -eq $true)} |Select -ExpandProperty Name

$PWChanged = @(Get-Content C:\Successful-Administrator.txt)
$RemainingUsers = $AllComputers | Where-Object { $PWChanged -notcontains $_ }

Foreach ($RemainingUser in $RemainingUsers){
Try {
$user = [adsi]"WinNT://$RemainingUser/Administrator,user"
$user.SetPassword("password")
$user.SetInfo()
Write-Host "$RemainingUser Administrator password reset"
$RemainingUser |Out-File C:\Successful-Administrator.txt -Append
}
Catch{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
Write-Host "$RemainingUser received error: $ErrorMessage"
$RemainingUser |Out-File C:\Errors-Administrator.txt -Append
#Write-Output "$computer received error: $ErrorMessage" +$Errors
}
}

$PWChanged = @(Get-Content C:\Successful-Administrator.txt)
$AllComputers | Where-Object { $PWChanged -notcontains $_ } |Out-File C:\Remaining-Administrator.txt
```

Comment: you have 3 output files and the 1st two use `$RemainingUser |Out-File`. are you certain that the display is "wrong" in only the 1st of those two files?

Comment: Yup. I just ran the script and it put the computer names in with the spaces in the successful file, it didn't in the errors file, and I ran another identical script where the only thing I changed was the account I was changing the password on, and all of the files append correctly on that script.

Comment: arg! i am out of ideas ... there is nothing that i see in your code that seems to relate to the difference. i will return to lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Hehe, see the comment below, I think that might be it. I'm reading through the link he provided now.

Comment: how very odd that encoding glitches would only show up on one of the files. in any case, thanks for the pointer to the fix! [*grin*]

Comment: I'm actually wondering if there is some hidden encoding character at the bottom of that particular text file that is screwing up the append results. It's not a big enough problem that I want to invest the time into deleting the file, recreating it, running more tests on it, etc.

Comment: That Encoding addition made things worse, so I ultimately just changed my outfile line to this and it worked: Add-Content -path pathtofile -Value $Remaininguser

Comment: you can add your own Answer to the ones listed for this Question. [*grin*] then you can change your `accepted` to the Answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the earlier suggestion of adding -Encoding utf8 and it added weird Chinese characters to my document instead of the computer names, so I tried changing the line to:

```
Add-Content -path C:\Successful-Administrator.txt -Value $Remaininguser
```

And that worked, it added the computer name without the spaces, and it added it correctly without extra characters or other weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the encoding to solve this issue

`$RemainingUser | Out-File C:\Successful-Administrator.txt -Append -Encoding utf8`

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: It saves the file with a curtain character set and layout. This blogpost explains it in detail http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/guide-data-character-encoding/

Comment: Wow, that's... a lot. I never knew about the BOM and ASCII stuff. great info, thanks!

Comment: I added the statement to the end, and now it's appending the names looking like this:䅃䡔剅义ⵅ則䡁਍䥒䭃䜭䅒䕃਍䅃卓乁剄ⵁ䅗協਍䅄䥖ⵄ䅒䥍ㅁ਍呓噅ⵅ䥈